# Postgres NetBeans connection driver issue

Tags: postgresql, netbeans

I am tryng to configure a connection to postrgresql db server via Services window of Netbeans 7.3.1 and I get the following error: 
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xx:5432/ using org.postgresql.Driver (ERROR: Unsupported startup parameter: extra_float_digits)

I have foud a possible workaround : 
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits 
Is there some way to set this parameter in a config file?

Thanks

Comment: What is your driver version and what is your Postgres version?

Comment: At a guess you're connecting to a truly ancient PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Postgresql is 9.0.3.2, the jdbc driver is postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem so far? I'm having similar issue.

Comment: I do not use netbeans client at the moment. I am waiting for a solution

Answer (score 1):

From PostgreSQL 9.2, a new server parameter `extra_float_digits` is added to control precision display of floating-point numbers [Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-7-4.html). I think that it is better to use the right jdbc version for your server PostgreSQL version(9.0.3.2). In your case [9.0-802 JDBC 4](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4.jar)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work, same error.